# SSH Agent forwarding not working on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I am trying to connect to github over ssh on my remote server (Running Ubuntu 22.04).

On my local computer (Running Win 10), I have `~/.ssh/config` file with the following:

```
Host remote
    HostName SERVER_IP
    port 22
    User ubuntu
    ForwardAgent yes
```

After connecting to the remote server, I can confirm that the ssh agent is working by typing:

`echo "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK"`

result: `/tmp/ssh-XXXXPWEKZo/agent.1073`

Also with `ssh-add -l` I see that the key is added

`4096 SHA256:hvGuLtIuwYi2LAnQ0KdC/9IgdBUmlHZer0NyXUXd5aY C:\Users\user/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)`

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` I have allowed Agent forwarding with `AllowAgentForwarding yes`

But when I try to connect to github `ssh -T git@github.com -vvv` (the key is added to github settings) I get the following:

```
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "github.com" port 22
debug3: resolve_host: lookup github.com:22
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.121.3] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-2f5f2727
debug1: compat_banner: no match: babeld-2f5f2727
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from github.com
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: have matching best-preference key type ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com, using HostkeyAlgorithms verbatim
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from github.com
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
channel 1: chan_shutdown_read: shutdown() failed for fd 7 [i0 o0]: Not a socket
debug2: get_agent_identities: ssh_agent_bind_hostkey: communication with agent failed
debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_fetch_identitylist: communication with agent failed
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug3: no such identity: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug3: no such identity: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I don't have such problems on other of my servers that are running ubuntu 20.04 and 18.04.

Comment: If you see the key with `ssh-add -l` on the remote server then your issue is not with agent forwarding. However your `ssh` logs show that it fails to communicate with the agent, have you run all these commands in order in the same terminal and shell on the remote machine? Please post the full `ssh -vvv` to have more debugging information.

Comment: Hello, I have edited the question with the full -vvv output.
On the remote server if I use the same key, but without forwarding (I manually upload it to the server) everything works Ok.

Comment: I just noticed while testing with the same key but without forwarding, that even if I add the key to the agent on the remote server, when connecting to github it says  `debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_fetch_identitylist: communication with agent failed` and it asks for the key password, so the problem should be with the agent on the remote server.
It's a clean install of Ubuntu 22.04 provided by ovh.com

Comment: I have the same issue, and it seems to be connected to the ssh-client on Windows. When I try a forward with an agent running on a linux, it works fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71399334/ssh-fails-to-use-private-key-from-ssh-agent-communication-with-agent-failed) helped me solve the same problem: there's some incompatibility between the ssh client shipped with Windows and the server on Ubuntu 22.04.

tldr: Installing [the most recent release of the windows ssh client](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases/tag/v8.9.1.0p1-Beta) fixed the issue for me.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/536604)

Comment: Note: do not just download the MSI file and click it, wishing everything will be done. Instead, RTFM here: https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH-Using-MSI

Comment: Note: the release link is stale, most recent can be found at the top of this page: https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @kaytwo is right; updating the Windows ssh client is the cure.

Here's what `strace -tt -f -v -s1024 ssh $hostname` revealed:

```
2636504 12:05:25.582068 write(3, "\0\0\0\320", 4) = 4
2636504 12:05:25.582159 write(3, "\33\0\0\0\30session-bind@openssh.com\0\0\0003\0\0\0\vssh-ed25519\0\0\0.....binary-data-omitted.....", 208) = 208
2636504 12:05:25.582210 read(3, "", 4)  = 0
2636504 12:05:25.875257 getpid()        = 2636504
2636504 12:05:25.875343 write(3, "\0\0\0\1", 4) = 4
2636504 12:05:25.875532 write(3, "\v", 1) = 1
2636504 12:05:25.875691 read(3, "", 4)  = 0
2636504 12:05:25.875745 getpid()        = 2636504
2636504 12:05:25.875799 write(2, "debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_fetch_identitylist: communication with agent failed\r\n", 87) = 87
```

Compare with `strace -tt -f -v -s1024 ssh-add -l`:

```
2648504 13:00:38.631807 connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/tmp/ssh-XXXXuWGsZN/agent.2628678"}, 110) = 0
2648504 13:00:38.632285 write(3, "\0\0\0\1", 4) = 4
2648504 13:00:38.632386 write(3, "\v", 1) = 1
2648504 13:00:38.632464 read(3, "\0\0\1\255", 4) = 4
2648504 13:00:38.920854 read(3, "\f\0\0\0\1\0\0\1\227\0\0\0\7ssh-rsa\0\0\0\3\1\0\1\0\0\1...binary-data-omitted.....", 429) = 429
```

Basically, sending a "session-bind@openssh.com" request causes the Windows ssh-agent to stop talking; the normal "list all keys" command doesn't return anything when it's in that state.  Fortunately, the state is cleared when the connection is closed, so you can try again without having to restart anything.

It looks like this configuration option (in `man ssh_config`) is related:

> ```
>  PubkeyAuthentication
>         Specifies whether to try public key authentication.  The argument to this keyword must
>         be yes (the default), no, unbound or host-bound.  The final two options enable public
>         key authentication while respectively disabling or enabling the OpenSSH host-bound au‐
>         thentication protocol extension required for restricted ssh-agent(1) forwarding.
> ```

Note: While that paragraph says `ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=unbound .....` should disable this protocol extension, strace showed that it was still being sent, and the Windows ssh agent won't work.

This page on [SSH Agent Restriction](https://www.openssh.com/agent-restrict.html) goes into total detail about the subject, from the reasons that inspired the feature to command-line options needed to use it and the byte sequences sent in the SSH Agent protocol extension.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is already answered but If you are here to look for a solution for an error like `chan_shutdown_read: channel 1: shutdown() failed for fd 7 [i0 o0]: Not a socket`

This only applies if you have installed [latest version of OpenSSH from GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH) and your forwarding agent suddenly stopped.

In my case after Windows update Forwarding Agent suddenly stopped working. I could connect the server but since my SSH key is not forwarded I could not able to push or pull from GitHub Private Repo using SSH and It was saying `access denied for public key`.

To confirm if the solution is same: Open `services.msc` and find `OpenSSH Authentication Agent`. Double click to open it's properties and check `Path to executable` section. If it is not `"C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\ssh-agent.exe"` and pointing to ssh agent in `system32` than this solution will work.

open `regedit` and head to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Services/ssh-agent`
Change `ImagePath` value to `"C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\ssh-agent.exe"` and restart the computer.

After restart make sure that `OpenSSH Authentication Agent` service is running then add your SSH key by typing `ssh-add` in PowerShell or CMD. Then your Forwarding should work.